# django wsgi "No module named models" error

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I'am having this issue with django + wsgi, and I can't understand why. When I go to my local website running with apache2 + wsgi, I have this error :

```
ImportError at /
No module named models
```

But when i run with development server, everything is ok : `python manage.py runserver 0:8080`.

My wsgi.py :

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/reader')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "reader.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Feed(models.Model):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link_feed = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

My views.py where the error is throwed :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from reader.models import Feed

def index(request):
    feeds_list = Feed.objects.all()
    context = {'feeds_list': feeds_list}
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

And in my settings :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'reader', <-- this is my app
)
```

I run under Python 2.7.4 and django 1.5.1.

Could someone explain to me why please ?

**Update 1 :**

```
jeremy@dev:/var/www/reader$ tree .
.
├── manage.py
└── reader
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── reader.settings
    ├── settings.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── images
    │   ├── scripts
    │   │   └── script.js
    │   └── styles
    │       └── style.css
    ├── templates
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── home
    │   │   └── index.html
    │   └── subscription
    │       └── add.html
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py

8 directories, 13 files
```

Comment: do you have `models.py` defined inside `reader` folder? `reader/models.py`?

Comment: is your project on your webservers python path? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#basic-configuration

Comment: @PauloBu yes, models and views are defined inside `reader` folder.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that in your project's app reader that there is an `__init__.py` file

```
project/
-- reader/
---- __init__.py 
---- models.py
---- views.py
```

### Debug help

Do you have `tree` installed?

if not `brew install tree` or `apt-get install tree` (change for your flavor of dev env.)

run

```
cd ~/path/to/djangoproject
tree .
```

and then paste the output up top so we can get a better idea of whats going on.

```
francis at Kraken.local  ~/Sites/yaconiello/blog on francis*
$ tree .
.
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── admin
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── article.py
│   ├── article.pyc
│   ├── category.py
│   └── category.pyc
├── feeds
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── category.py
│   └── latest.py
├── migrations
│   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   ├── 0002_auto__add_field_article_excerpt.py
│   ├── 0002_auto__add_field_article_excerpt.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── models
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── article.py
│   ├── article.pyc
│   ├── category.py
│   ├── category.pyc
│   ├── request.py
│   └── vote.py
├── signals.py
├── signals.pyc
├── templates
│   └── blog
│       ├── article
│       │   ├── category_archive.html
│       │   ├── date_archive.html
│       │   ├── index.html
│       │   └── single.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── emails
│       │   └── new_comment.html
│       ├── feeds
│       │   └── description.html
│       └── snippets
│           └── article_list.html
├── templatetags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── blogs.py
│   └── blogs.pyc
├── urls.py
├── urls.pyc
└── views
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── article.py
    └── article.pyc

12 directories, 45 files
```

### UPDATE

Your project is reader. so that `reader` folder is project level folder not app level. You really shouldnt have project level models or views. Create an app and move your models and views into it. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610797/884453

Additionally b/c its `reader/reader/models.py` you probably have the project folder on the path and so `reader.models` doesn't exist, but `reader.reader.models` i bet does.

Comment: Yes, i have `__init__.py`, which is the default one, i mean it is empty. Do i need to overwrite it ?

Comment: no as long as its there, you python code should be able to see `models.py`... do you see an `__init__.pyc` and `models.pyc` files? those 2 files would indicate that your python code is able to see/interpret the contents of the reader app.

Comment: These are no `.pyc` files now. I have edited my question in order to add the `tree` result.