# Django best practice: Should I split non-app specific models into my project folder?

Tags: django

I am going to extend the django user models - is it best practice to create a new models.py in my project directory: I.e:

```
project
     application
         migrations
         static
         models.py (all my application specific models)
     project
         forms.py
         urls.py             
         views.py 
         *** project models.py ? ***
```

I want to add email confirmation to my user sign up. So basically just extend the user model. I am thinking this may not be best practice to do in my application models, but for this case it is only going to be one model so would not really matter. However if I want to extend more non-application specific models then it might be better to do this in a separate file?

Does anyone do anything similar and have any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think putting model inside the project is a food idea, but its practical possible.

For your case I would create an app called `utils` and put those models there. In real sense i don't think there is non-app specific model . . . correct me if I am wrong.

**Plus** you can have as many `apps` as you want

Also you can check [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610727/django-project-models-py-versus-app-models-py) for more